# Fraction to Recurring Decimal

Tags: java, algorithm

Working on this problem, and also did a few reference to similar solutions. One thing I am confuse is, why we break the loop as long as there is one repetitive number? Is it possible the number repeat for 2-3 times and then changed to another different number? Thanks.

I mean this part specifically,

```
        if (map.containsKey(num)) {
            int index = map.get(num);
            res.insert(index, "(");
            res.append(")");
            break;
        }
```

**The problem,**

Given two integers representing the numerator and denominator of a fraction, return the fraction in string format.

If the fractional part is repeating, enclose the repeating part in parentheses.

For example,

Given numerator = 1, denominator = 2, return "0.5".
Given numerator = 2, denominator = 1, return "2".
Given numerator = 2, denominator = 3, return "0.(6)".

```
public class Solution {
    public String fractionToDecimal(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if (numerator == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        // "+" or "-"
        res.append(((numerator > 0) ^ (denominator > 0)) ? "-" : "");
        long num = Math.abs((long)numerator);
        long den = Math.abs((long)denominator);

        // integral part
        res.append(num / den);
        num %= den;
        if (num == 0) {
            return res.toString();
        }

        // fractional part
        res.append(".");
        HashMap<Long, Integer> map = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
        map.put(num, res.length());
        while (num != 0) {
            num *= 10;
            res.append(num / den);
            num %= den;
            if (map.containsKey(num)) {
                int index = map.get(num);
                res.insert(index, "(");
                res.append(")");
                break;
            }
            else {
                map.put(num, res.length());
            }
        }
        return res.toString();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code doesn't stop when it sees a digit repeated. It stops when it notes that it has reached a state which it was already in. If it reaches the same state again, it means that we are about to repeat a division that we have already done, which means that the dividend and remainder are going to be the same, and we are going to do the same series of steps we have already done.

When that happens, it means a repetition, and it stops and adds the parentheses.

For example, let's divide 123 by 999. This should give us the repeating decimal 0.123123123..., so the output should be `0.(123)`.

- 123 / 999 is 0. The remainder is 123. We start with `0.`
- Multiply the remainder by 10. Now we have 1230 / 999. Dividend is 1, remainder is 231. Now we have `0.1`
- Multiply the remainder by 10. Now we have 2310 / 999. Dividend is 2, remainder is 312. Now we have `0.12`
- Multiply the remainder by 10. Now we have 3120 / 999. Dividend is 3, remainder is 123. Now we have `0.123`
- Multiply the remainder by 10. Now we have 1230 / 999... wait, we have already done that! That means that as we continue to divide, we'll get to that number again and again. Stop and put parentheses around the repeating part.

The map is there to tell us which numbers we have already divided, and at which index in the `StringBuilder`. When we find a number we have already divided, we use that index to know where to insert the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly it's possible to have a decimal number with two or more decimals recurring and then a different decimal. For example 449/1000 = 0.449

Comment: Thanks William, do you think the code I posted above is correct? My confusion is, I searched a few solutions to learn from, it seems all of them are doing similar like this. If you have any insights, appreciate for sharing. :)

Comment: It is not correct to interpret the fractional part to be recurring as soon as the same number occurres twice in a row (this is what the code seems to be doing).

Comment: Thanks William, so you think the code is wrong I posted? :)

Comment: I think the code is not right. The recurring part could even consist of more than just one number. For example 123 / 999 = 0.123123123... So here the output should be 0.(123), I guess.  The mathematically interesting question is how do we know when the decimal part is recurring. Obviously, if the denominator is 9 * 10 ^ n, the decimal part is recurring, the length of the recurring part being n. This happens also when the denominator is 3 * 10 ^ n. But are there other cases in addition to these, that's the question...

Comment: The code is right, and it's not putting brackets when there is just one repetition. You can test it with exactly the example you gave: 449 and 1000, and it gives `0.449` without parentheses.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks, you are right. After reading the code more carefully I see that the test "if (map.containsKey(num))" tests not just the occurrence of the last decimal but the occurrence of the whole numerator.

So, for example in the case of 123 / 999 it will put the parenthesis as soon as it finds 123 in the decimal part.

Comment: Yes, William, it seems the code and RealSkeptic are both correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution in Java to this problem:

```
/**
 * Given two integers a and b, return the result as a String.
 * Display the repeating part of the fraction in parenthesis.
 *
 * Runs in O(b)
 *
 * @author Raed Shomali
 */
public class Divider {

    private static final String DOT = ".";
    private static final String ERROR = "ERROR";
    private static final String LEFT_PARENTHESIS = "(";
    private static final String RIGHT_PARENTHESIS = ")";

    public static String divide(final int a, final int b){
        if (b == 0) {
            return ERROR;
        }

        int value = a / b;
        int remainder = a % b;
        return String.valueOf(value) + DOT + divider(remainder, b);
    }

    private static String divider(final int a, final int b) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> remainderIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
        final List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

        int value;
        int remainder = a;
        while (!remainderIndexMap.containsKey(remainder)) {
            remainderIndexMap.put(remainder, values.size());

            remainder *= 10;
            value = remainder / b;
            remainder = remainder % b;
            values.add(value);
        }

        final int index = remainderIndexMap.get(remainder);
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            result.append(values.get(i));
        }
        result.append(LEFT_PARENTHESIS);
        for (int i = index; i < values.size(); i++) {
            result.append(values.get(i));
        }
        result.append(RIGHT_PARENTHESIS);
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Basically, the idea is simple. Using the same long division technique, you know when to stop when you have already seen the same `remainder` value.

Here are some test cases to show a few different scenarios:

```
divide(0, 0)     // "ERROR"
divide(1, 2)     // "0.5(0)"
divide(0, 3)     // "0.(0)"
divide(10, 3)    // "3.(3)"
divide(22, 7)    // "3.(142857)"
divide(100, 145) // "0.(6896551724137931034482758620)"
```

If you are interested in a solution written in `Go`, you can find it here https://github.com/shomali11/util

Answer (score 0):

This problem is actually very simple to solve if we use the long division technique that we learnt in 4th grade.

Suppose you need to divide 92 by 22. How do you do it using the long division method. How do you detect a repeating pattern?

Simple, you know you have a repeating pattern of decimals when you encounter a *previously encountered reminder*. You'll need to store the reminders and the corresponding index of the result in a dictionary and using the same you could detect/print repeating decimals. Working python code below.

```
def divide(numerator, denominator):
    sign, res, lead = '', '', ''
    if (numerator < 0) ^ (denominator < 0) and numerator != 0:
        sign = '-'
    numerator = abs(numerator)
    denominator = abs(denominator)
    remainders = defaultdict(list)

    if numerator < denominator:
        lead = '0'
    _x = str(numerator)
    r = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while True:
        if i < len(_x):
            d = int(str(r)+_x[i])
            q = d // denominator
            if not (q == 0 and len(res) == 0):
                res += str(q)
            r = d - (q * denominator)
            i += 1
        elif i >= len(_x) and j <= 9223372036854775807:
            if r == 0:
                return sign+lead+res
            if j == 0:
                remainders[r] = [True, len(res)+1]
                res += '.'
            d = int(str(r) + '0')
            q = d // denominator
            res += str(q)
            r = d - (q * denominator)
            if remainders[r] and remainders[r][0]:
                res = res[0:remainders[r][1]] + '(' + res[remainders[r][1]:] + ')'
                return sign+lead+res
            remainders[r] = [True, len(res)]
            j += 1
        else:
            return sign+lead+res
```